# What is the difference between single quoted $'string' and double quoted $"string" in bash?

Tags: bash, quoting, echo

I was trying to execute new line using `echo` and tried following two commands:

1. First command:

   ```
   echo $'Hello World\nThis is a new line'
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   Hello World
   This is a new line
   ```
2. Second command:

   ```
   echo $"Hello World\nThis is a new line"
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   Hello World\nThis is a new line
   ```

My question is what's the difference between string wrapped with `$' '` vs string wrapped with `$" "` in `bash`'s `echo`?

Comment: Helpful note : Double quote is also known as weak quoting and Single quote is also known as strong quoting.

Comment: Yes, but `"weak quote"` and `'strong quote'` are different from `$'C String'` and `$"I18N String"`.

Comment: You the real MVP. :D >>> @DopeGhoti

Comment: I do what I can (:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting), the syntax `$'string'` specifies a C-style string which includes magic escaped characters, such as `\n` for a newline.  `$"string"` is for I18N expansion, which has no such magic escapes.

Note that these are distinct from the more common `"string"` (weak quoting) and `'string'` (strong quoting).

Answer (score 9):

The `$` in the beginning of the string in :

```
echo $'Hello World\nThis is a new line'
```

causes escape sequences to be interpreted.

Bash reference manual [[ says ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
>   string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>   ANSI C standard.
>   ..
>   ..
>   The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

But

```
echo $"Hello World\nThis is a new line"
```

is completely different. This [[ article ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Locale-Translation.html) on locale specific translation says :

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (‘$’) will cause the
>   string to be translated according to the current locale. If the
>   current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the
>   string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

---

<sup>**Note:** IIRC both `$'string'` and `$"string"` may not find support among different shells. Not only do people from other shells look at them with curiosity but also they debate on whether this could be avoided for script portability.</sup>

Comment: `ksh93` also understands `$'...'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : Hmm, Good note :)

Comment: `$'xxx'` is not a bashism but was first introduced by `ksh` several years before `bash` did. It is currently also supported by `zsh` and `busybox sh` and is under review by the POSIX standard.

Comment: @jlliagre : Appreciate the time  :) . I stand corrected..