# awk is not working for my requirement

Tags: shell-script, awk, find, variable

My requirement is that shell script should print the folder name of the file.

For example comp.class is present in D:/Practice/HelloWorldPractice/bin folder, I should get output after executing command is **bin**.

My command searches a file and prints the full path of that file .
After that, it removes the filename from full path.
At the end, it remove everything except folder name of file.

**code**

```
filesDirName="/D/Practice/HelloWorldSagar"
file=comp.class
echo $(find "${filesDirName}" -name ${file}) | awk -F '${file}' '{ print $1 }'| awk -F '${filesDirName}' '{ print $2 }'
```

**output**
    empty output

**code**

When I am entering below command in terminal it is working fine.... But when I am doing it through variables, I am not able to get output.

```
echo "$(find "/D/Practice/HelloWorldSagar" -name comp.class)" | awk -F 'comp.class' '{ print $1 }'| awk -F '/D/Practice/HelloWorldSagar' '{ print $2 }'
```

**output**

/bin/

Comment: I get this is some kinf of homework or tutorial (or else you can use `$(basename $(dirname $f))`  to get folder name of `$f` ). 1) there is non need to echo $(find ...) 2) I wouldn't use a directory name as separator. 3) use `-F/`  and `NF` 's awk variable. `$NF` is last field and `$(NF-1)` the one before.

Comment: Could you please explain why my code is not working? Because I want to make work my above code as my file might be present inside subdirectory of another subdirectory. In that case, I need to print path in the way like /bin/hello.

Comment: See [What's the difference betwen " and ' - and when to use it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344000/whats-the-difference-betwen-and-and-when-to-use-it)

Comment: Thank you so much............. :) It worked :) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `comp.class` as the field delimiter (or trying to, the variable expansion is single quoted in your code) for `awk` makes little sense to me, as does running multiple `awk` programs ofter each other in a pipeline.

As far as I understand you want the filename of the directory that contains the `comp.class` file.

This does that:

```
topdir='/D/Practice/HelloWorldSagar'
filename='comp.class'

find "$topdir" -type f -name "$filename" \
    -exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "$1")"' sh {} ';'
```

This looks for all files called `comp.class` in or below `/D/Practice/HelloWorldSagar`.  When one is found, a short shell script simply prints out the base name (the filename portion of a pathname) of the directory path of the found pathname.

Alternatively, look for directories, and then separately test for the existance of the file:

```
find "$topdir" -type d \
    -exec test -f {}/"$filename" ';' \
    -exec basename {} ';'
```

This tests for existence of `comp.class` in all found directories under `$topdir` (including `$topdir` itself).  When the file is found, the base name of the found directory is printed.

The difference between the two approaches is that the second approach would also detect a *symbolic link* called `comp.class` that points to a regular file.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

Just in case it's not the base name of the directory you want, but the relative path beneath `$topdir`:

```
find "$topdir" -type f -name "$filename" \
    -exec sh -c 'd="$(dirname "$2")"; printf "%s\n" "${d#$1/}"' sh "$topdir" {} ';'
```

This is a variation of the first solution that extracts the directory name into a variable `d`, and then prints the value of that directory pathname with `$topdir` deleted from the start of it.